# Next.Js page is not crawlable by the google even if page is not broken

Tags: javascript, next.js, web-crawler, seo, google-search-console

I just finished up my next.js music application [beatsbajao](https://beatsbajao.com) and uploaded to live server. Then I submitted my site to google search console. After few days when I checked there was an error in the search console and pages were not indexed.

**Screenshot of google search console.**
[image]

Then I checked with some of the crawlers like [https://www.siteliner.com](https://www.siteliner.com/) and [alphacrawler.pro](https://alphacrawler.pro/app/) to crawl my site and they were also not able to crawl many of the pages from site and getting 500 error.

For the first time I was using  without baseUrl of site like given below

```
<Link href="/foo/bar"><a>Go to another page </Link>
```

and tested it with [alphacrawler.pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfh5N.png) and it was showing me some errors i.e. page broken.
Then I decided to change  tag and added baseUrl of every  tag given below

```
<Link href="https://beatsbajao.com/foo/bar"><a>Go to another page </Link>
```

In both the scenarios the app works fine in browser but the issue comes when crawlers want to crawl the site and it finds that the page is broken.
I am not sure why the page is not getting crawled by the crawlers.
[image]

Above is the screenshot of crawler result which shows the broken page even if it is not broken and can be accessed using that url shown in the screenshot.

I am not able to figure out why crawler is getting 500 error. If this is fixed may be Google can start indexing my site. The project can be seen here [beatsbajao.com](https://beatsbajao.com)

Comment: Bots and crawlers won't work with client side rendering because the time they get to page its fetching js to render and crawlers couldn't find anything. what you can do is set some data default on the index.html page or use ssr where you need bots to crawl and index.

Comment: @danish-khan-I I have used SSR only in all the pages.

Comment: Google works well with client-side rendering. You have to provide additional information and should read carefully [Googles page indexing report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en). We can't see even the full URL of 500 pages. Your server (which?) return HTTP status code 500. First resolve this issue. Does GSC report 500 too? ...

Comment: @Stefan in GSC too it is showing this https://ibb.co/M5Pxwvf

Comment: Please read my comment above. I'm out here.